# python pip disappearing from venv "no module named pip"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv, pyenv

Recently my pip seems to have weird behaviour.

First When I set up my virtual environment using `python3 -m venv env` everything works fine and I can use pip to install packages once I activate the environment.

For some reason, if I let the project sit for a while and return later, using pip to add a new package will throw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ugn/Documents/Code/Commercial/overtitle/overtitle-build/env/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried entering "where pip" which resulted in this:

```
/Users/ugn/Documents/Code/Commercial/overtitle/overtitle-build/env/bin/pip
/Users/ugn/.pyenv/shims/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

So pip is definitely part of my environment but seems to not be accessible.
Also, this looks a bit like Pip is in too many different locations for me?

I'm using Pyenv to switch between Python versions, is there a possibility It is not connected with Pip in the right way, why does it work in the first place then and just stops working after a while?

Using Python version 3.11.5

Comment: `where pip` lists `pip` **scripts**, not `pip` **modules**.

Comment: does `python3 -m pip` work?

Comment: @phd thank you, I was aware of that. I included it to demonstrate that there is definitely a pip installation in my environment even though it is saying "pip not found"

Comment: @JonSG I just reinstalled my env as I had to work on it, I will try this next time it comes up and update you. I tried "python -m pip" but not "python3 -m pip"...

Comment: The error message was "No **module** named 'pip'" so 'where' doesn't show much.